# sqlite3 file is encrypted or is not a database while simply trying to list the tables of said database

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to open a database with sqlite3 version 3.7.9 that I previously created in sqlite version 2.8.17. All I'm trying to do is simply list the tables currently in the database with the .tables command and I get the error message.
The operating system I'm running is ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite 3.x.x is incompatibile with SQLite 2.x.x. You will need SQLite 2.8.17 to open your database.